# Custom Pipeline Component SSIS Error: HREF 0xC0048021

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to implement a custom data flow component in my managed code.  Here is my custom data flow component:

```
[DtsPipelineComponent(DisplayName = "RenameComponent", ComponentType = ComponentType.Transform)]
public class MapperComponent : PipelineComponent
{
    List<IDTSVirtualInputColumn100> dontMapList;

    public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
    {
        base.ProvideComponentProperties();

        base.RemoveAllInputsOutputsAndCustomProperties();
        IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
        input.Name = "Input";

        IDTSOutput100 output = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New();
        output.Name = "Output";
        output.SynchronousInputID = input.ID;

        // Make the output asynchronous
        output.SynchronousInputID = 0;
        FindOldColumns(input);
    }
}
```

I compile that, register it with the gac, and save it to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents directory.

I then run the following code to add the component to my data flow task:

```
private static IDTSComponentMetaData100 CreateRenameTransformation(MainPipe dataFlow, Train train)
    {
        IDTSComponentMetaData100 renameTransformation = dataFlow.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();

        // Set stock properties
        renameTransformation.ComponentClassID = "Dexter.CustomComponents.MapperComponent";
        renameTransformation.Name = "RenameTransformation";
        renameTransformation.Description = "Rename and remove incompatible columns";

        CManagedComponentWrapper instance = renameTransformation.Instantiate();
        instance.ProvideComponentProperties();

        return renameTransformation as IDTSComponentMetaData100;
   }
```

During runtime (when i try to create the pacakge), I get the following error: 
0xC0048021
-1073446879
DTS_E_ERRORCOMPONENT
The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "%1".

Thanks,

Comment: Also fyi, when i read all the PipelineComponentInfos componentInfos = application.PipelineComponentInfos; Component creation names, Dexter.CustomComponents.MapperComponent is registered.

Comment: Just to verify I understand what you're doing. You've create a custom data flow component, registered and installed it. You are attempting to *use* the component by creating a package via the SSIS object model and *that's* when it fails? What if you use BIDS to perform the same tasks?

Comment: How come you are not adding the component to BIDS? I think you will have to add the component to BIDS in order to use it in the package.

Comment: billinkc, yes that is what I am doing.  When i try to add it in BIDS i get a different error - "this package does not have a working component".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had faced the same problem "Error Code: 0xC0048021" and solved it. This problem occurred due to the Script Component added in the Data Flow Task.

I installed this version of SSDT from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383

Then, in the SSDT solution explorer right click the Project,go to the Properties --> Configuration Properties --> TargetServerVersion = SQL SERVER 2014

Then, in the SSDT solution explorer right click the Project, go to the Properties --> Configuration Properties --> Debugging --> Run64BitRuntime = False

Referring to this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssis/archive/2016/03/03/what-s-new-for-ssis-2016-rc0.aspx

Comment: link no longer works: 'http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssis/archive/2016/03/03/what-s-new-for-ssis-2016-rc0.aspx' (404)